# Maven tries to download ojdbc14.jar again - jar already present in local repository

Tags: java, maven-2, maven, maven-plugin, nexus

When I run the command **mvn eclipse:eclipse**, the dependency jar ojdbc14.jar is getting downloaded without any issues. Then, when I run the command **mvn clean install**, maven tries to download the same jar again - but this time it fails saying that the jar is not found in the repository.

What I have noted is that, when running the command for the first time (**mvn eclipse:eclipse**), Maven looks into the Nexus repository of our company - and it finds the jar. When running the command **mvn clean install**, maven directly goes to the central repository without looking into Nexus - and hence it is not finding the jar.

1) Why is maven trying to download the jar when it is already present in the local machine?

2) Why is maven skipping the Nexus repository before going to the central repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you problem is related to you maven settings file. Does you settings file catch  calls to all remote repositories for example like this:

```xml
<mirror>
  <!--This sends everything else to /public -->
  <id>nexus</id>
  <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
  <url>http://yournexusrepoaddress</url>
</mirror>
```

If not, downloaded pom files could override where to look for external repositories. See [this link](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/maven-sect-single-group.html) for more information. I hope that this helps.

Comment: Oystein, Thanks for the reply! Does it still allow Maven to go to the central repository when required?

Comment: No it doesn't, but isn't that the point with using a Nexus server. In my opinion your Nexus server should be proxying Central, and then all those artifacts ends up in Nexus instead of on all developer machines and/or build servers. It is possible to exclude central from the catch all with somthing like this _!central, *_, but I would not recommend it. This says catch all other repos than central. I am not sure if the above command is case sensitive so it might not work exactly as written (maybe Central instead).